# count words in string element in a tab delimited file

Tags: arrays, string, scala, apache-spark

I have a tab delimited text file.  I need to extract the second element, and do word count only on words that appear in the second element.  (I also need to filter words that are less the 3 characters, and want to display the word as a key and count as value in descending order of count.)

I can read in the file using

```
scala> val lines = sc.textFile("MYDIR/myfile").map(_.split("\t"))

scala> lines.take(3)
```

I get `Array[Array[String]]` =

```
Array(Array(abc, Here is the First Text, en, Thu Sep 26 08:25:42 CDT 2013, null),
      Array(def, and here is the Second text, en, Thu Sep 26 08:27:22 CDT 2013, null),
      Array(ghi, and here is Another text, en, Thu Sep 26 08:50:21 CDT 2013, null))
```

If I map to get the second eliments

```
val wrdStr = lines.map(ar=>ar(1).toLowerCase)

wrdStr.take(3)
Array[String] = Array(here is the first text, and here is the second text, and here is Another text)
```

I want to do the basic wordcount, but if I `.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))`,  and add the ,1 to each word,  I no longer have an RDD, so when I attempt to do the reduce action it fails.  How can I implement the word count?  once I mapped to the second element?

Comment: `Array` has same `reduce` operation as `RDD`, you can do `arrayStr.reduce(_ + _).split(" ").size`

Comment: Can you expand a little more?  thanks

Comment: actually it's hard to explain without clear problem statement. `Array(here is the first text` (`arrayStr` in my code snippet) can be easily reduced to one string (using `reduce`), which pretty much answers your headline question.

Comment: But if you use Spark you probably have to care about scalability, so it's better to stay with RDD as Ramesh Maharjan pointed out. Otherwise it makes no sense to read your file with Spark - you could use regular `scala.io.Source` API. Simply saying: if file is small (fits into RAM), there is no reason to use Spark at all.

Comment: Thank you,  this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
wrdStr.flatMap(line => line.split("\\W+"))
    .filter(word => word.length > 2)
    .map(word => (word, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .sortBy(x => x._2, ascending = false)
    .foreach(println)
```

You should have the following output

```
(text,3)
(here,3)
(and,2)
(the,2)
(second,1)
(another,1)
(first,1)
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  if I do them step by step I am OK upto wrdStr.flatMap(line => line.split("\\W+")).filter(word => word.length > 2).map(word => (word, 1))  but then the reduce failes  wrdStr.reduceByKey(_ + _)
<console>:32: error: value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
              wrdStr.reduceByKey(_ + _)

Comment: it should be `.reduceByKey(_ + _)` and not `.reduceByKey(_ + )` . You missed the ending `_`

Comment: This was a typo here only.  I had it correct at the scala> prompt.....      
scala> val wrdStr = lines.map(ar=>ar(1).toLowerCase)
wrdStr: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at <console>:29

scala> wrdStr.flatMap(line => line.split("\\W+")).filter(word => word.length > 2).map(word => (word, 1))
res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at <console>:32

scala> wrdStr.reduceByKey(_ + _)
<console>:32: error: value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
              wrdStr.reduceByKey(_ + _)

Comment: `scala> wrdStr.reduceByKey(_ + _)
<console>:32: error: value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
              wrdStr.reduceByKey(_ + _)
                     ^
`

Comment: why are you applying reduceByKey on the separate line ? it should be applied to the transformed (k,v) and not on wrdStr. Please use it as i have done in the answer. :)

Comment: `cala> wrdStr.flatMap(line => line.split("\\W+")).filter(word => word.length > 2).map(word => (word, 1)).reduc                                              eByKey(_ + _).sortBy(x => x._2, ascending =false).foreach(println)
17/11/03 23:16:46 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, w10.gps.stthomas.edu, exec                                              utor 2): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at $line37.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:31)
       `  when I do this I get the big stack dump...

Comment: That error seems to be at line37. Please update the question with full stacktrace and your full code

Comment: Feeling like a total idiot...  I was running it against a big data file that had many short records.  so there was not second element in the array... Works great now, once I filter against lines with less than 2 elements.    Thank you!!!

Comment: great to hear that @Rachel. you can upvote too if it helped you :)